# Порядок загрузки сервисов на Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, asterisk

На сервере с Ubuntu 16.04 установлен asterisk с модулем dahdi. При перезагрузке сервера asterisk стартует до момента инициализации dahdi. Вручную модуль chan_dahdi при этом не загружается. Только выполнив dahdi_cfg, можно загрузить модуль в asterisk. Вопрос в том, как сделать чтобы сначала выполнялось dahdi_cfg, а затем запускался asterisk?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В Ubuntu имеются папки для загрузки в различных режимах

```
/etc/rc0.d
/etc/rc1.d
/etc/rc2.d
/etc/rc3.d
/etc/rc4.d
/etc/rc5.d
/etc/rc6.d
```

5 - многопользовательский графический режим, 3 - многопользовательский сетевой режим (обычно в нем работают сервера). В папках находятся ссылки на службы (которые обычно располагают в /etc/init.d), загружаются они в алфавитном порядке. Для того, чтобы сервис стартовал раньше другого, достаточно назначить ему имя ссылки, которое будет идти по алфавиту раньше другого сервиса

```
/etc/rc3.d
...
S10dahdi_cfg -> ../init.d/dahdi_cfg*
S20asterisk -> ../init.d/asterisk*
```